# How to show a loading indicator while relations of route model load

Tags: ember.js

I have a resource route in my Ember app that successfully loads the model its supposed to per the model hook of the route. While that model is being loaded, I'm able to use a loading route that displays an animated gif to let the user know.

In that same view, I'm rendering a list items in a hasMany relationship for that model. As a possibly important aside, the list in the view is actually rendered using an abstracted view that requires the controller to return the items in the relationship using a specific property name rather than the name of the actual relationship property on the model.

The problem: I'm able to display the relationship items, but they take a second or two to load, during which there's no indication to the user that they are loading. Is there a way to track the status of loading of that relationship?

Below is some of the code involved:

```
// From router...
App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('item', params.item_id);
  }    
});

// From item model...
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  things: DS.hasMany('thing', {
    async: true
  })
});

// From controller...
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  myList: function() {
    return this.get('things');
  }.property('things')
});

// From view...
{{#each v in myList}}
  <div>{{v.id}}</div>
{{else}}
  <div>Your list is empty.</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the flags that are made available in Promises: [Ember.PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html)

What you are asking can be achieved with `isSettled`:

```
{{#if things.isSettled}}
  {{#each things}}
    {{id}}
  {{else}}
    Your list is empty
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  {{!-- Show loading spinner here --}}
  Loading...
{{/if}}
```

In order for this to work you need to trigger the request of the `things` records. You can do this in the `afterModel` callback of the route:

```
App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('item', params.item_id);
  },

  afterModel: function(model) {
    return model.get('things');
  }    
});
```

Comment: I actually need to be looping through `myList` rather than `things`, but either way I can't seem to get `isSettled` to work. I tried adding `Ember.PromiseProxyMixin` to `ItemController` but no luck.

Comment: @AndrewKamm updated my answer. `myList`, as it is defined, is identical to `things`.

Comment: Still no luck. The `isSettled` property never changes to `true` even after the the list loads. That being said, all I've done with `Ember.PromiseProxyMixin` is to include it with `ItemController`, but I'm guessing there's more required to make it apply activate it's properties (like `isSettled`) on the `myList` property (I just can't figure out what that is in this context).

Comment: @AndrewKamm it would be helpful if you can setup a fiddle to test on it. By the way you don't have to include Ember.PromiseProxyMixin anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i haven't tested it but i think it should work.

```
 // From controller...
 App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   thingsLoaded : false,
   myList: function() {
       if(this.get('thingsLoaded').then){
           var self = this;
           return this.get('things').then(function(data){
              self.set('thingsLoaded', true);
           });
       } else {
           return this.get('things');  
       }
   }.property('things')
 });
```

Comment: I get an error in the console from this: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'then'`

Comment: Ok updated my answer, so the function "then" only exists for a promise. Once the promise is resolved this.get('things') will point to Record array(i think) which doesn't have then function.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should create two functions

```
function loading(){
//display gif
}

function loadingOff(){
//hide gif
}
```

And then add these functions inside the functions that takes time to load.

EX:

```
function loadImage(){
loading();
//code
loadingOff();
}
```